# Why are Ruby versions conflicting when launching Rails server?

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I am using rbenv on OS X. When I run `ruby -v`, I get "ruby 2.0.0p195" but when I launch `rails s` I get:

```
Gemfile syntax error:
/myapp/Gemfile:14: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end
gem "mysql2", group: :mysql
```

It seems that the `Gemfile` is processed using Ruby 1.8.7. Why is it so?

Comment: What is the output of `which rails`?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall it ouputs `/usr/bin/rails`

Comment: Open a new shell, and add the output of `rbenv shell 2.0.0-p195; gem env; gem list rails` to your question by appending it. Then add the output of `rbenv shell system; gem env; gem list rails`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don’t have Rails installed in your rbenv Ruby installation, so it’s falling back to the `rails` system binary which is hardcoded to use the system Ruby. Simply `gem install rails` while using your rbenv Ruby installation.